# How to compare two timestamps in this format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, comparison

I have two timestamps formats say,

```
a='2014-01-15 00:00:00.0'
b='2014-01-16 00:00:00.0'
```

How to compare and find if b is after a or not?

Comment: Shouldn't simple string comparing be enough in this case?

Answer (score 7):

You may need to do something like this,

```
d1 = new Date("2014-01-15 00:00:00.0");
d2 = new Date("2014-01-16 00:00:00.0");

if ((d1 - d2) == 0) {
    alert("equal");
} else if (d1 > d2) {
    alert("d1 > d2");
} else {
    alert("d1 < d2");
}
```

### [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XXUUg/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var a ='2014-01-15 00:00:00.0';
var b ='2014-01-16 00:00:00.0';
if (b > a) {
// do stuff
}
```